# Section's heading in small caps

Tags: sectioning, formatting, small-caps

I am using TeXmaker and I am trying to format the section's title. I tried something I had found on the internet but it was clashing with another package. How can I set all section's heading to be written in small caps ?

This is the preamble of my document

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}

\renewcommand{\section}{\smallcaps}

\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textsc{Tableau}}}

\bibliographystyle{test}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend using the KOMA replacement to `article` as it's far more flexible and it makes it much easier to change that kind of thing.

**Edit:** I've removed `lmodern` and made the section heading centered and bold.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\addtokomafont{section}{\mdseries\rmfamily\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\rmfamily\centering\scshape}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a lot of vertical spacing that was not there before. How can I center it and make it bold ?

Comment: @esmitex You can't have bold small-caps with `lmodern` (which was why I used `\mdseries` in my example). Use a different font package and remove `\mdseries` (and add `\centering` to center it).

Comment: By the way I get a weird extra space when I use the class {scrartcl} (see the picture): http://i50.tinypic.com/qz3b54.jpg ; that I don't have with the class {article}: http://i50.tinypic.com/2d9biq1.jpg

Comment: @esmitex Can you provide a minimal example? (It would be better posted as a separate question.) I can't reproduce that effect.

Answer (score 8):

The `titlesec` package allows you to do this with the standard article class with the line:

```
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: When I use \usepackage[sc]{titlesec} I get the error message : "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

Comment: @esmitex Did you remove the wrong line `\renewcommand{\section}{\smallcaps}`?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\scshape}{\thesection.}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{behold small caps}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I really don't know why but my document doesn't work with use package{titlesec}

Comment: Several packages are sensitive to the order in which they're loaded relative to other packages.  Try putting `\usepackage{titlesec}` last and then let it percolate upwards until you stop getting compilation complications.

Comment: Well, it is the last one already. I will put it at the beginning. It seems to be clashing with what I use to make the document with 2 columns.

Comment: works fine, gets smashed by \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}, make sure to uncomment (if ok)