# Easiest Way To Make Section Smallcaps

Tags: fonts, sectioning, small-caps

I am trying to make my sections small caps. I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\section*{\textsc{Test}}
\end{document}
```

But this complains that no bold small caps font exists. How can I unbold the sections and as a bonus automatically make them small caps? I tried looking at `titlesec` but I found it quite confusing as I am a beginner.

Comment: Do you really want to `unbold` the sections?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I assume that's the only way to make small caps work. If there's a way to get both works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83001) (using the `titlesec` package):

```
\documentclass{article}

% mighty titlesec package
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

> I just googled **formatting headings latex small caps**...

Answer (score 2):

Here is `sectsty` way just make things complete.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%% \allsectionsfont{\normalfont\scshape}  %% for all sectional levels

%% \normalfont since CMR doesn't have bold small caps. If you use some other font like libertine then you can have bold small caps.
\sectionfont{\normalfont\scshape}      %% only for sections
\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is another way using same `titlesec` but this will make only section headings small caps (not subsubsection etc).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\scshape}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```