# How do I type the word "Bibliography" in Small caps?

Tags: biblatex, small-caps

In my thesis I have all of the chapter names written in small caps (Professor asked me to do it). I use `biblatex` for automatic bibliography, but it generates the usual title without sc.

Since it is the only "chapter" non written in small caps, I would really appreciate whoever could help me to obtain it in sc as well.

Here I add my MWE as suggested in comments:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{provainternet.bib}
@book{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010,
  title = {Il Discorso Di {{Eraclito}}: Un Modello Semantico e Cosmologico Nel Passaggio Dall'oralitÃ  Alla Scrittura},
  author = {Gianvittorio, Laura},
  date = {2010},
  publisher = {{G. Olms}},
  location = {{Hildesheim}},
  isbn = {978-3-487-14386-6},
  keywords = {Eraclito}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin,greek.ancient,english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=archaeologie, doi=false, url=false,isbn=false,backend=biber, style=archaeologie, bibstyle=philosophy-verbose, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,scauthors=cite]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{provainternet.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\textsc{my first chapter}}
\section{\textsc{my first section}}

I cite this\footcite{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you need chapter titles in small caps you should consider setting your document up in a way that it automatically makes your chapter titles small caps without additional markup. How that is possible depends on your document class and your sectioning setup. Then you *probably* get the bibliography title in small caps automatically. If that is not the case one would have to figure out how exactly the bibliography title is typeset. But that also requires knowledge about your document class, your sectioning setup and your bibliography setup. ...

Comment: ... I guess what I am saying is: Please share a short example document with us that shows which document class you are using, what code you have in your preamble to format chapters, sections etc., how you generate your bibliography and how you normally typeset your chapter headings.

Comment: Dear @moewe, thank you so much for your quick reply. I have added a MWE, I hope it can give the required information

Comment: Adding to what @moewe says, wouldn't something like \printbibliography[title=\textsc{My Bibliography}] work?

Comment: Adding that simple command it seems to work, thank to the both of you @moewe and @Ingmar!

Comment: I strongly recommend against throwing in `\textsc`s everywhere. It is usually much nicer and makes for a cleaner document to try to let LaTeX do the work of formatting the section headings as desired.

Comment: I really appreciate your kind suggestion! I did my final work two months ago, now I was helping a friend who can not use Latex (neither can I, apparently). I did not have so many trouble doing mine, but her Professors is asking much more issues, so I had to resort to requests and strategies different from those I have already learned to use, ending up doing a coarse syntax. Thank for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your chapter/section titles in small caps, set your document up to automatically format section headings in small caps. Do not add `\textsc` in every heading command.

With the `book` class you can use `titlesec` ([Section's heading in small caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83001/35864), see also [How to set the font for a \section title (and chapter etc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1455/35864)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin,greek.ancient,english, italian]{babel}

\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber, 
  bibstyle=philosophy-verbose, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
  scauthors=cite
  doi=false, url=false,isbn=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
\section{My first section}

I cite this\footcite{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography heading in small caps.]

Comment: Thank you! If I add \textsc to every chapter however I obtain chapters in small caps AND in bold, is it possibile to have this effect even with this titlesec package?

Comment: @andrea.i Try `\usepackage[sc,bf]{titlesec}`.

Comment: The `titlesec` has many more ways to influence the output. The package options are probably easiest to use, but if you need more detailed control, there are lots of other commands that you can use. Have a look at the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) or questions on this site.